# Do countries other than the US operate "intranets" like the SIPRnet or JWICS?

Tags: internet, technology

...and what are they called?

[SIPRNet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIPRNet) is an intranet system operated by the US government for the passage of information classified as SECRET or lower. [JWICS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joint_Worldwide_Intelligence_Communications_System) is an intranet system operated by the US government for the passage of information classified as TOP SECRET or lower.

I assume that they would, but I don't know the names for them or any specific information. I am most interested in countries not explicitly allied with the US.

Comment: I think you could improve this question with a short explanation of what SIPRnet or JWICS are, or by precising what kind of "intranets" you are looking for.

Comment: Specially relevant would be te technical details. Many business have intranets and VPN. Some bigger organizations may contract dedicated communications circuits with their providers. Very few organizations will own and manage their WAN infrastructure. And maybe https://security.stackexchange.com is a better site to ask (check their FAQs).

Comment: The very first line of the help center reads "Politics Stack Exchange is for objective questions about governments, policies and political processes."

How is the operation of a *government intranet* intended for the passage of restricted information "off topic"?

Comment: This question is downright silly.  Anyone with a home router operates an intranet. If that router is not connected to the Internet in anyway, it's a closed network.  It's almost impossible to fathom that *any* country would *not* operate a closed network for need-to-know-only information.  I am going to take the really unpleasant step of voting to delete this question.

Comment: The question is not whether countries have intranets, but whether or not they have intranets like JWICS or SIPRnet. The US is the wealthiest country in the world, why would we assume that all capabilities inherently replicate themselves among less wealthy countries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the desk next to me at work in Australia is a terminal for the Defense Restricted Network (DRN) there is also a secret equivalent.

I know that the UK also has equivalent systems, that come under the umbrella of Defense Gateway

A quick google suggests that the [Russian](https://www.scmagazineuk.com/dedicated-military-intranet-to-help-defend-russian-armed-forces/article/651124/) equivalent is called Closed Data Transmission Segment (CDTS), although I'm not sure how reliable that is, as you can imagine information on secret networks is not widely published.

There are also a large number of non-military networks out there like [JANET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JANET) which is used by UK universities

Comment: JANET is open to the Internet though (and I would wager that a significant fraction if not the majority of traffic on it is going to or from the Internet).

Answer (score 2):

North Korea operates what possibly is the largest intranet. It's called [Kwangmyong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kwangmyong_(network)) As of 2014, Kwangmyong is estimated to have between 1,000 and 5,500 websites.